# wget can't download apache tomcat 8

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, wget, centos7

I am trying to install Apache Tomcat 8 through these instructions: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-centos-7

I am using centos 7.2 on a virtual machine.

When i run the command wget http://mirror.sdunix.com/apache/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.23/bin/apache-tomcat-8.0.23.tar.gz i get this every time:

> Resolving mirror.sdunix.com (mirror.sdunix.com)... 74.206.97.82
>   Connecting to mirror.sdunix.com
>   (mirror.sdunix.com)|74.206.97.82|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
>   Retrying.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You get this error probably because this mirror is not responding anymore, try this:

```
wget http://www-us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.38/bin/apache-tomcat-8.0.38.tar.gz
```

Or if you need the exact same version, try this:

```
wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.23/bin/apache-tomcat-8.0.23.tar.gz
```

Comment: On 28thAugust-2017 : wget http://www-us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.0.M26/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26-deployer.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

Version has gone up to 39 and you have to use https.

```
wget https://www-us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.39/bin/apache-tomcat-8.0.39.tar.gz
```